# Elements of maximal order generate this abelian $p$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

A subgroup in which every element has order a power of a fixed prime $p$ is
called a $p$-(sub)group.

> A finite abelian $p$-group (Exercise 7) is generated by its elements of maximal
> order.

Each subgroup / element has order power of some prime and if $|G| = p^n$, there exist an element of each order $p$ such that $p^i$ for $0\leq i<n$.

Now, I have to prove that it is generated by an element of order $p^n$ , hope I am correct!  But I am at loss of ideas.

Do you mind giving some hints?

Comment: You have to prove it is generated by the set of *all* elements of maximal order: there may not be one of order $p^n$, and a single element usually won't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will prove that a finite abelian p-group is generated by its
elements of maximal order.

Let $G$ be an Abelian group of order $p^n$ and let $M$ be the set
of all elements of maximal order $p^m$. (Note in parentheses that
generally speaking $m\leq n$.) Let $H=\langle M\rangle$.

We will prove that $H=G$.

Let $g\in G$ and $\operatorname{ord}(g)=p^k<p^m$.
Let us choose $h\in H$ such that $\operatorname{ord}(h)=p^m$.

Then $(gh)^{p^k}=g^{p^k}h^{p^k}=h^{p^k}$. It
follows that $\operatorname{ord}(gh)=p^m$ (think about why) and hence $gh\in H$.
Since $g=(gh)h^{-1}$ therefore $g\in H$.

Comment: Where are you using the finiteness?

Comment: @sim642 Here it is: "(Note in parentheses that generally speaking m≤n.) " By the way, for infinite $p$-groups the set $M$ can be empty.

Comment: But the rest of the proof does nothing with this $n$, so it might as well be infinite as long as the maximal order is finite. Where does the rest of the argument break down if $n$ isn't finite if it's nowhere used?

Comment: @sim642 Yes, you're right.
The rest of the reasoning is independent of $n$.
It only requires that $M\neq\varnothing$.